# convert numeric up down value to time format

Tags: vb.net

I have one NumericUpDown1 control
if i select 5 in numeric up down control.the i am calling that value like this:

```
NumericUpDown1.Value
```

that return value 5 like integer instead of getting 5.
i want to get that value in time format
I if i select `5`.that should return `00:05:00`..
how i can convert numeric up down value to times..
in my data base i want to store that value the data type time(7).I tryed something like this:

```
Dim value As TimeSpan = Convert.ToDecimal(NumericUpDown1.Value)
```

but that is getting error

Comment: An easier way is to use the DateTimePicker, change the format to show just time and add scroll buttons, now you can scroll each value up or down and/or the user can type the value and your value is in a datetime variable already

Answer (score 2):

You are using `TimeSpan` wrongly, better rely on `Date`:

```
Dim value As Date = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 0, NumericUpDown1.Value, 0)
```

You can convert this variable into a string with the format you want by doing:

```
Dim valueAsString As String = value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

This is the right way to use `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim value As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, NumericUpDown1.Value, 0)
```

But I do recommend the `Date` alternative above. Use `TimeSpan` just for measuring intervals (between `Date` type variables) and better store date/time-related information as `Date`, which is easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks sir..i got answer,what i expected

Comment: @user2603688 you are welcome, as suggested by matzone, please award the question if you think that it is the right one.